# In older k8s, will a very small readiness window and a large liveness window result in a "bricked" pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I work in an enterprise using k8s v1.13.12, a pretty ancient version, but we have no choice right now.

We run hundreds of services running Java SpringBoot services.

I have some questions about readiness.  We have one service where the readiness window (period * failurecount) is extremely small (4 seconds).  It has an initial delay of 120 seconds.  The liveness window is much larger, and the initial delay is 170 seconds. The service can take somewhere between 1-4 minutes to start the listener, depending on resources.

If the pod takes 3 minutes to start up the listener, then the readiness probe will fail.

What's not clear to me is what happens next.  As far as I know, k8s doesn't continue to check for readiness after it has reached the failure count.  Is that true?

Note that when I've asked about this, people have mentioned that we should be looking at "startup probes".  As far as I can tell, startup probes were added in k8s v1.20, so they would not be available to us.